# Typescript: Get intellisense for valid function parameters

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, nestjs, intellisense

Within a nest.js service: I have a service method that takes an error code and outputs a message which is later on displayed to the user. The following method is a shortened version of it:

```js
  getGenericErrorMessage(input: string): string {
    const errorMessages = {
      unknownError: 'An unknown error occurred. ',
      noResponse: 'The Application did not send a response. ',
    };
    return errorMessages[input] || errorMessages['unknownError'];
  }
```

Is there a way to get intellisense for valid function parameters that are defined as keys in `errorMessages`? Or is there any way I can restructure my code to archive this?

Comment: do you want this to be done automatic or allow you to hardcode the type of the input parameter with the possible options, you can try to use an enumeration type outside the function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can move `errorMessages` out then use `keyof` like this:

```
const errorMessages = {
  unknownError: 'An unknown error occurred. ',
  noResponse: 'The Application did not send a response. ',
};

function getGenericErrorMessage(input: keyof typeof errorMessages): string {
  return errorMessages[input]; // <--- // `input` must be `unknownError` or `noResponse`, so you can remove the fallback
}
```

If you want to discuss further, leave a comment below

Comment: And if you don't want `errorMessages` to be exposed, you can wrap this in an `iife` and return just the function.

Comment: As I am in a nest.js service (which is a class) I can not define `errorMessages` outside of the function. Or if I do I can't access `errorMessages` in the function. Making `errorMessages` a public property also didn't work, I still can't access it.

Comment: @dude Can you provide a codesandbox or a snippet of your class? Even inside of a class context, you should still be able to read `errorMessages`, be it a public/private instance variable or a separate constant, so I don't get how you are having that problem.

Comment: Here is the code in a playground: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMYBsCGBnDCC2BPVTbAb2AXIQgFcAjFASyQRBhlgFkQs0BzLhALwJSFBFQB2Aa3FQA7uICirWAC4EAcgCC4sVJnzmymAihIkVViAAmAOg0AaMhRkAlLtHEYQa9QBUAFiAImhAQDEhocPRQOlb0VggyiF7iCWgIMO4xXnbqjqIAvgDcwE7kfHAA4iDiLIxKbDCc3HwAFPTi1HBqkiB4UABmCHB4ECCDho3NGLxcAJRqGHAwHTzCZaIZIHAWOixTXDN8GADaHV0AukUIAPQ3CAA8ALQvt-cABudUcO+4VEsIGhBd4SaRyRRGX6wBDvVxZTwgd72BAYKAIfpUZBoHSZHBQABuQTggQQAzQKBQNDQSEkGwKpQowHpwCQ2UQ+A6S2xSCCQlqslwBHQWFacxKrM8UBQIBsKCgPFaHM8cG5Moq1VqKyQDQ4h1mrQARKD9BDGga5mKgA

Comment: Note that I already got a solution which I already find satisfying. Thank you for your help! I just leave this open because I want to know if we get your solution to work. My soulution has the downside that all options need to be repeated.

Comment: @dude I see your problem, making `errorMessages` an instance variable will result in a TypeScript error when `this` is used in a method parameter's type. Unfortunately I don't have the solution for that, but you can use a `static` variable instead, it'll work and IMO it's better since each instance doesn't need to create a new `errorMessages` object.

Comment: Here's the example https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAgMYBsCGBnDCCyBPVTbAb2AXIQgFcAjFASyQQzjTkYRBhlhxCzQBzfggC8CUhSkIqAOwDWsqAHdZAUW6wAXAgDkAQVkyFS1Z00wEUJEircQAEwB0egDRlp5JQCV+0WRggOroAKgAWIAj6EBAMSGz0UEYO9A4ISoiBsmloCDB+SYEuuu5SAL4A3MAe5MJwAOIgslyMGjwwfALCABT0stRwOvIgeFAAZghweBAg47gE6FhOXO2dGEL8AJQ6LDB9ghI10vlwdkb4hEsrvPzrwhgA2n0DALoVCAD0HwgAPAC0AM+3wABs8qHBgQgALZUFgIGiRYFyRQqdQWSGwBDAnwFAIgYGuZhQBCjKjINBGfJQqAAN0icAiCDGaBQKBoaCQ8iOZWqFGAPOASEKiCheD6LApSEi4maynmlww3U2VSFASgKBAThQUEE3VF4tYsilTjqjWaeyQbRuXRA3QARMjTGj2nbNsqgA

Answer (score 0):

My current solution is using the [literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types):
The resulting code looks like this:

```js
export type ErrorType = 'unknownError' | 'noResponse';
@Injectable()
export class MyService {
  constructor() {}
  getGenericErrorMessage(input: ErrorType): string {
    // take identifier from error name if input is an error
    const errorMessages = {
      unknownError: 'An unknown error occurred. ',
      noResponse: 'The Application did not send a response. ',
    };
    return errorMessages[input];
  }
}
```